# I get an error in the Ubuntu terminal

Tags: android, recovery-mode

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my PC and i decided it's time to make a custom rom for my phone (MIUI V5 in this case) I used the instructions from the patchrom developer guide from the MIUI Porting contest running till 31 October 2013. Every time after entering a series of commands including adb reboot recovery(which means my device is enabled in ADB) and it's working. But when i come to the part when i have to enter (tools folder directory)/ota_target_from_phone -r i get an error that the command is not found. Can someone tell me what's the problem. I have the latest versions of Android SDK, and Android Kitchen on my pc. I still don't know what causes this problem.

[image]

See this image and please see what's the problem

Now the command works but I get another error It say's device not found. About the previous error: I wasn't entering the directory right

Comment: What's the actual error message? Plese [edit] your question to include the output of `uname -a`, `file (tools folder directory)/ota_target_from_phone` and `stat (tools folder directory)/ota_target_from_phone`.

Answer (score 0):

If the command you need to issue is inside the `tools` directory you need to type it like this:

```
./ota_target_from_phone -r
```

This is because your `tools` directory is not in your PATH.